# Proving every real number is a limit of a sequence of rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I have to prove the following:

Given an $x\in\mathbb{R}$, there is a sequence $r_n\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $r_n\to x$ when $n\to\infty$.

This is my attempt:

Let $x$ be a real number. For any natural number $n$ we have that $x-\frac{1}{n}<x+\frac{1}{n}$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, there is a $r_n\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $x-\frac{1}{n}<r_n<x+\frac{1}{n}$. Note that $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}x+\frac{1}{n}= \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}x-\frac{1}{n}=x$. Then, by the squeeze theorem, $r_n\to x$ when $n\to\infty$.

Is this argument correct?

Comment: How do you know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$? That might be relevant to avoid a circular argument.

Comment: We already proved that in class so I skipped the proof.